# GKTurnBasedMatch participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome

Tags: ios, game-center

I am working on a a turn based Game Kit game. I am making a custom UI for the matches that a player is involved in. I get the matches using

```
loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:
```

There is a use case where the user is in a match, it is not their turn and they want to quit and no longer see that match in the list of games. My code calls

```
participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:withCompletionHandler:
```

and deletes the row from a table view.

At this point the other player gets the turn and sees their opponent has quit

```
match.remoteParticipant.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit
```

so they end the game with a call to

```
endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:completionHandler:
```

The issue is that the game still exists in Game Center. So calling

```
loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:
```

on the first player's app will pull it back down and display it in the table of games.

The only solution I can think of is to save the match id and blacklist that match from the table. Seems a bit cludgy.

It appears there is not an API for this. i.e. quit and remove the match my list of matches. Is there a better way to handle this situation only using the Game Center APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set the matchOutcome property on each participant to something other than GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeNone before you can remove the match. From the docs:

> Calling this method ends the match for all players. This method may only be called by the >current participant. Before your game calls this method, the matchOutcome property on each >participant object stored in the participants property must have been set to a value other >than GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeNone.